# How to position a two colored ellipse produced by the three lines below?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-positioning

This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [thick,x=1mm,y=1mm]
    \draw (0:0) ellipse (10mm and 20mm);
    \draw[fill=red] (0:0) -- (0:10 and 20) arc (0:180:10 and 20) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue] (0:0) -- (0:10 and 20) arc (0:-180:10 and 20) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces an ellipse with a filldraw red upper part and a blue lower part.

Problem: how to position this ellipse with the coordinates (x,y)?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[fill=red] (3,2) -- +(0:1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, x radius=1, y radius=2] -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue] (3,2) -- +(0:1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-180, x radius=1, y radius=2] -- cycle;
\draw[orange,->] (0,0)node[above]{(0,0)} -- (3,2)node[above]{(3,2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red and blue ellipse and arrow]

Comment: Thank you so much. That was very helpful. There are so many variants around which are incomplete. This is what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

Your ellipse is centered at point `(0:0)` = `(0,0)`, i.e. the origin of the current coordinate system.

You either change this coordinate to something else or you shift your coordinate system:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [thick,x=1mm,y=1mm]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(x,y)}]% ← Use any coordinate you want here.
    \draw (0:0) ellipse (10mm and 20mm);
    \draw[fill=red] (0:0) -- (0:10 and 20) arc (0:180:10 and 20) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue] (0:0) -- (0:10 and 20) arc (0:-180:10 and 20) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  % The following dot will not be at the center of the ellipse:
  \fill (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you need to put this ellipse more than once in your document you could pack this all into a custom macro or a TikZ pic, depending on what your goal is.

Here's a simple implementation with a pic that allows you to set the center of the ellipse.

I've moved the `\draw` after the `\fill` (which don't draw anymore) so that the border of the ellipse doesn't get covered by any fills.

I'm also using only one coordinate system (the [`canvas` one](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.canvas) with units) and don't mix it the `xy` coordinate system (which multiplies the given values with the `x`/`y` lengths).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  my ellipse/.pic={
    \tikzset{start angle=0, x radius=10mm, y radius=20mm}
    \fill[red]  (0:0) -- (0:10mm and 20mm) arc [delta angle= 180] -- cycle;
    \fill[blue] (0:0) -- (0:10mm and 20mm) arc [delta angle=-180] -- cycle;
    \draw (0:0) ellipse[];
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-3.5,-1.5) grid (2.5,4.5);
\pic at (1,2)  {my ellipse};
\pic at (-2,1) {my ellipse};
\fill (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]